# Form data on submiting to transfer to json file as object

Tags: php, json, ajax, html

**My form is like:  HTML**

```
    <form class="form-horizontal demo-form">
    <fieldset>        
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="From Range" data-field="l1_price.from" id="from">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="To Range" data-field="l1_price.to" id="to">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Price" data-field="l1_price.price" id="price">      
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="From Range" data-field="l2_price.from" id="from">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="To Range" data-field="l2_price.to" id="to">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Price" data-field="l2_price.price" id="price">      
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="From Range" data-field="l3_price.from" id="from">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="To Range" data-field="l3_price.to" id="to">
            <input type="text" required="" class="form-control input-md" placeholder="Price" data-field="l3_price.price" id="price">      
        </div>
    </div>     
    <div class="form-group">
        <label for="submit" class="col-md-4 control-label"></label>
        <div class="col-md-5">
            <button class="btn btn-success" id="submit">Submit</button>
        </div>
        </div>
   </fieldset>
</form>
```

**My Java Script Code:**

```
$("form")
    .serializer()
    .on("serializer:data", function (e, formData) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(formData));
    });
```

**Json Object**

```
"range":{
        "l1_price":
            {"from":"0", "to":"260k", "price": "Rs 2"},
        "l2_price":
            {"from":"260k", "to":"500k", "price": "Rs 4"},
        "l3_price":
            {"from":"500k", "to":"1MM", "price": "Rs 7"},
        "l4_price":
            {"from":"1MM", "to":"2MM", "price": "Rs 3"}
     }
```

**But Actual Json Object**

```
{
    "range":{
        "l1_price":
            {"from":"0", "to":"260k", "price": "Rs 2"},
        "l2_price":
            {"from":"260k", "to":"500k", "price": "Rs 4"},
        "l3_price":
            {"from":"500k", "to":"1MM", "price": "Rs 7"},
        "l4_price":
            {"from":"1MM", "to":"2MM", "price": "Rs 3"}
     },
     "rates" : [".02",".04",".007",".003",".002"],
     "thresholds": [26e4,5e5,1e6,2e6,3e6]
}
```

Problem With rates and thresholds how can i get it dynamic from the form or above json range array